# Block Quantity increase if product become out of stock

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

i have a simple question.
If i have a product set to quantity equal to 4, and a client increase the quantity to shop at 5 products, the transition will be ok and my product quantity become equal to -1.

How can i block increase of my product to 4 elements ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should turn off this option "Allow ordering of out-of-stock products".

There are 2 places you can do that:

- For every single products: Edit a product > tab Quantity > Change "When out of stock" to "Deny order"
- For all products (default mode): Preferences > Products > Change "Allow ordering of out-of-stock products" to "No".

Hope this helps!